# How to make changes in project json file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I need to update my Stripe Public Key which get from api

```
 var jsonText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/google_pay_payment_profile.json');
 data.value = json.decode(jsonText);
 data['data']['allowedPaymentMethods'][0]['tokenizationSpecification']
     ['parameters']['stripe:publishableKey'] = LocalStorage.stripePublicKey;
```

I make change in data but how to push this changes in json file?

Comment: Checkout here https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: I want to change in projects assets file this article shows how to change in local files which stored in mobile storage

Comment: You can try saving the json to local files. Project's assets can't be changed when they are packed (apk, aab).